# Ответ на мой POST-запрос после авторизации

Tags: python, веб-программирование, requests

Посылаю на сервер следующий запрос:

```
session = requests.Session()
url = 'http://example.ru/system/autorization.php'
headers = {'Host': 'example.ru',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Content-Length': '55',
            'Origin': 'http://example.ru',
            'Connection': 'close',
            'Referer': 'http://example.ru/',
            'Cookie': '_ym_uid=0; _ym_d=0; _ym_isad=0; PHPSESSID=0'}
data = 'login={}&pass={}&typeEnter=2&action=checklogin'.format(login, password)
page = session.get(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

И теперь мне нужно проверить, что сервер меня авторизировал. Сам сервер в ответ на подобное посылает такой Response (отследил через burp), мне такого не приходит:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 11 Mar 2021 12:07:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.36
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: token=0909090990; expires=Thu, 18-Mar-2021 12:07:12 GMT; Max-Age=604800; path=/; domain=example.ru
Content-Length: 34

{"errors":"","urlEnter":"worker"}
```

Как вытянуть последнюю строку из ответа? и как вообще его получить?

Comment: `page.text` пробовали? Или `page.json()`, чтобы сразу в виде словаря получить.

Comment: пробовал. Выводит пустое сообщение

Comment: А print(page) что выведет? Возможно какой-нибудь статус ошибки возвращается, типа 403

Comment: Кстати, почему session.get, если вам POST запрос нужно послать?

Comment: нет, 200 выводит

Comment: я и так, и так пробовал. Одинаковый вывод абсолютно

Comment: И так и так не надо, надо `session.post`. `Сам сервер в ответ на подобное` - как "подобное" отправляете, этим скриптом или как-то по-другому?

Comment: Так. Я нашел костыль: запрашиваю доступ к странице, на которую можно зайти только авторизированным пользователям. Но если будет вариант, как можно это сделать быстрее, буду безумно благодарен

Comment: переделал в post. Отправляю через скрипт

Comment: В общем, ответ на ваш вопрос: "последнюю строку" (тело HTTP ответа) можно получить через `page.content` (в виде байт), `page.text` (в виде строки), `page.json()` (в виде словаря). Если не получаете - значит что-то не так делаете.

Comment: Понял, большое спасибо!